# Locate the ".Rprofile" file generating default options

Tags: r, rprofile

In R and RStudio, I think I have messed around with the `.Rprofile` file a few times, and I currently am loading up an old version of it upon startup of R or RStudio, is there a way that I can quickly find the location of the file that is generating the default options?

Thanks

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Like @Gsee suggested, `?Startup` has all you need. Note that there isn't just the user profile file, but also a site profile file you could have messed with. And that both files can be found in multiple locations.

You could run the following to list existing files on your system among those listed on the page:

```
candidates <- c( Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE"),
             file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site"),
             Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER"),
             file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile"),
             file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile"))

Filter(file.exists, candidates)
```

Note that it should be run on a fresh session, right after your started R, so that `getwd()` will return the current directory at startup. There is also the tricky possibility that your profile files do modify the current directory at startup, in which case you would have to start a "no-profile" session (run `R --no-site-file --no-init-file`) before running the code above.

Comment: Nice. Should probably also check `"~/.Rprofile"` (or, more formally, `file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile")`, since it's searched as well.

Comment: Very detailed steps, Thank you, I guess the search order is 1.the current directory. 2.the home of R(or where ~ points to) 3 the place you install R/etc

Comment: What is meant by "`getwd()` will return the current directory at startup"? Is the current directory that which I see when I click the Terminal tab and type `$ pwd` ?

Comment: Your suggestion didn't work, but @JoshO'Brien 's comment works. Do you understand that?

Comment: @Wassadamo kinda late to the party but getwd() returns your current working directory which tipically ends up being where the directory on which you started R
so lets say your in /micron/ and you type R in terminal executing the binary in path 
if you do getwd() it will return /root/

Comment: It should be noted that the `candidates` list is incomplete (see @JoshO'Brien's comment), that at most one `.Rprofile` file is being sourced (see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/articles/360047157094), and that the order of the `candidates` does not match their search order (compare https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/startup/vignettes/startup-intro.html).

Comment: If using RStudio, you should also consider the Project directory. `file.path(.rs.getProjectDirectory(), ".Rprofile")`. It will likely be the same as `getwd()` but the user may have navigated to another path since opening the project