# What is the difference betwwen `Rprofile`,`Renviron` and `Rprofile.site`,`Renviron.site`?

Tags: r

In my computer:

1. There are three files in /etc/R
   `Renviron` and `Rprofile.site`,`Renviron.site` ,
   I can not find `Rprofile` anywhere. Is that a proper status?
2. What is the difference beetwen `Rprofile`,`Renviron` and `Rprofile.site`,`Renviron.site`?

Comment: This is almost certainly answered in `?Startup`, though I will admit that the documentation there can be a bit of a slog to read through.

Comment: @it_is_a_literature:  you appear to be firing off questions without any clear effort of search either the R help system, or the corpus of existing StackOverflow question.  That is not going to be a successful strategy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name of the file is `.Rprofile` rather than `Rprofile`. I got this code after doing a search in SO for '[r] .rprofile' and finding this answer:[Locate the ".Rprofile" file generating default options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options)

```
file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile") 
[1] "/Users/davidwinsemius/.Rprofile"
```

Most OSes will hide "dot-files"/"system files" unless you force them to become visible.

You will find the various files described in the `?Startup` help page. The `.Renviron` file is supposed to describe settings and locations of system resources; from `?Startup

> Lines in a site or user environment file should be either comment lines starting with #, or lines of the form name=value. The latter sets the environmental variable name to value, overriding an existing value.

So the key-value pairs will be used to push those pairs to the system environment variable table. `Rprofile.site` is supposed to contain code that creates starting conditions for everyone on a network, perhaps shared options such as the setting for `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`,

... and `.Rprofile` contains code that an individual user sets up and controls, perhaps user defined functions or packages to be loaded at startup.

Josh cited an answer by @flodel that deserves study: [Locate the ".Rprofile" file generating default options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options/13736073#13736073)

Answer (score 1):

I had a question similar to question 2 from the OP, but specifically focused on the difference between the .Rprofile and Rprofile.site files.

Based on what I've gleaned from `?Startup` and some of the other answers on SO here's my understanding of that difference:

Rprofile.site is the site-wide startup profile - it gets searched for, and run, BEFORE .Rprofile and it will overwrite the base package. .Rprofile is a user startup profile that gets searched for and sourced AFTER Rprofile.site and loads stuff into the workspace rather than overwriting the base package.

I also found [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options/13736073#13736073) helpful in understanding the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this article](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2017/04/19/r-for-enterprise-understanding-r-s-startup/) useful for answering the OPs second question, "What is the difference between Rprofile, Renviron and Rprofile.site, Renviron.site?" Essentially, Rxxx.site contains site-specific (i.e. current computer) settings, while .Rxxx contains project- or user-specific settings.