# R and RStudio don't find Rprofile.site

Tags: r, windows-7

I've installed RStudio on Win7 following all the defaults, etc.  I've also modified the Rprofile.site file to require a number of packages I use regularly, but when I start R, it doesn't source the Rprofile.site file.

Also, all the documentation mentions the .Rprofile file, but I cannot create a file with a leading '.' on Win7.

Any suggestions??

Comment: any luck with my suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of reply.  Your suggestion for creating a . file on Windows was very helpful.  As for positioning the .Rprofile, finding the right directory was a bit of a haul.  A combination of you your stackoverflow link and a lot of Google gave us the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `?Startup`, there are plenty of possibilities.

This answer also has a command giving a few (all?) of the candidate locations https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736073/1201032.

Finally, make sure you are not running R in `--vanilla` or `--no-site-file` mode as either will bypass the reading of the profile site file. I suppose Windows 7 is no different than previous versions so right-click your shortcut to the R application, select Properties, and check the target.

Finally, here is a link to a question for creating a file with a leading '.' under Windows 7: [How to manually create a file with a . dot prefix in windows for example .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004633/how-to-manually-create-a-file-with-a-dot-prefix-in-windows-for-example-htacce)