# What might have caused R to behave like setting the seed to a specified number at startup?

Tags: r, rstudio, random-seed

I have used the following as an example

```
x <- 1:12
sample(x)
```

Whenever I restart RStudio or Rgui and run that code, I always get the same result:

```
 [1]  7  3 10  8  2  9 11  4 12  5  1  6
```

Is there a way to change this annoying behavior?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Greek_Greece.1253  LC_CTYPE=Greek_Greece.1253   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Greek_Greece.1253 LC_NUMERIC=C                 
[5] LC_TIME=Greek_Greece.1253    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

Comment: Do you have other things loaded automatically at startup?

Comment: hm... it's not Rstudio. RGui does the same.
I deleted everything I had in Rprofile, but still I get the same result.

Comment: Do you have a `.Random.seed` in your workspace that is being restored when you start R? `ls(all=TRUE)` will show stuff beginning with a dot, which are normally hidden.

Comment: I do, indeed. 
> ls(all=TRUE)
[1] ".Random.seed"

Comment: How can i get rid of it? `rm(list = ls(all=TRUE))` doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you tried starting R in `vanilla` mode?

Comment: The local `.Rprofile` file is not the only file potentially sourced by R at startup. All locations are documented in `?Sartup`. This http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options/13736073#13736073 might help you list such files. Search them for a call to `set.seed`.

Comment: @flodel That code listed only my .Rprofile file which does contain a set.seed command.

Comment: `rm(.Random.seed)` and save workspace (`save.image()`). Note this behaviour is by design. If you restore a workspace, you restore the RNG seed, restoring the state of things.

Comment: @Spacedman Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly include a line:
    `set.seed(NULL)`