# New .Rprofile not loading at start of R

Tags: r

I recently changed a statement in .Rprofile. It was to load a source file:

```
source("/home/theuser/olddir/myfile")
```

This statement is in .First <- function() of .Rprofile file.

I changed it to:

```
source("/home/theuser/newdir/myfile")
```

However, on starting R, I am getting following error message:

```
cannot open file '/home/theuser/olddir/myfile': No such file or directory
```

R still looks for old file. How can I correct this. Thanks for your help.

The .Rprofile is:

```
$ cat .Rprofile

options(tab.width = 2)
options(width = 130)
options(graphics.record=TRUE)
options(show.signif.stars=FALSE)

.First <- function(){
 library(Hmisc)
 #library(R2HTML)
 source("/home/theuser/newdir/myfile")
 cat("\nSuccessfully loaded .Rprofile at", date(), "\n")
}

.Last <- function(){
 cat("\nGoodbye at ", date(), "\n")
}
```

Comment: Where is `.Rprofile` located? Does R displays this error if run in the root of your home directory?

Comment: Any `.Renviron` or `Rprofile.site`?

Comment: You can search in your home directory: `ls .R*` and `ls *.site`.

Comment: There are: .RData  .Rhistory  .RLPlot  .Rprofile . No *.site file.

Comment: Can you `source("/home/theuser/newdir/myfile")` in R?

Comment: Yes, I can and that is what I now do to load it.

Comment: Possibly, it is running another Rprofile file, try http://stackoverflow.com/q/13735745/1201032

Comment: The ouput is: "/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site" "/home/theuser/.Rprofile"  (All lines in Rprofile.site file are commented)

Comment: ok... Is your Rprofile sourcing a file that itself sources `/home/theuser/olddir/myfile`? Can you add `print` statements to your files to guide you to the problem?

Comment: I have added .Rprofile file in question above.

Comment: If you don't need the .RData, remove it and try again.

Comment: Yes, it worked: "Successfully loaded .Rprofile at Fri Sep 19 ..." Please enter this as an answer so that I can accept it and thanks for your efforts.