# R Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

Tags: r, jdbc, rjava

trying to install stringi package in R but getting weird error message, below.

```
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘stringi’ had non-zero exit status
```

Looked in other postings but they are all related to DB drivers. No clue what may be causing this in my case, any help appreciated. Many thanks.

Specs: Mac OSX, R Studio, R version is 3.2.0.

UPDATE:

Apparently this issue happens to the installation of other packages too. Below is the output when trying to install DierckxSpline.

```
> install.packages("DierckxSpline", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")
Warning in install.packages :
  dependency ‘PolynomF’ is not available
also installing the dependency ‘fda’

Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open: HTTP status was '404 Not Found'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://R-Forge.R-project.org/bin/macosx/mavericks/contrib/3.2
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘DierckxSpline’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source packages ‘fda’, ‘DierckxSpline’

trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/fda_2.4.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1034752 bytes (1010 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 1010 KB

trying URL 'http://R-Forge.R-project.org/src/contrib/DierckxSpline_1.1-9.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 785060 bytes (766 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 766 KB

Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fda’ had non-zero exit status
Loading required package: DBI
Loading required package: rJava
Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
Execution halted
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘DierckxSpline’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/99/kh3ryr751csc6rnw79nzj0k40000gn/T/RtmpS3HGiF/downloaded_packages’
```

I have no clue so far, and nothing helpful when I Google it. It seems to be a Mac X issue with RStudio. Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: Oh, yes, it's Mac OSX. I'm using R Studio, and the R version is 3.2.0.

Comment: Is this the whole output from running `install.packages("stringi")`? Because I can't see why stringi would want to install DBI and rJava - they're not explicit dependencies and stringi's dependencies seem quite light and shouldn't be pulling in DBI and rJava.

Answer (score -1):

Finally got the answer and solved it, here:
[rJava 'class not found' error with makeCluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35451334/rjava-class-not-found-error-with-makecluster). The issue was in my `.Rprofile` which had the line `library(RJDBC)` and the line `drv <- JDBC("com.sas.net.sharenet.ShareNetDriver", "/usr/local/sas/jdbc_driver/sas.intrnet.javatools.jar", identifier.quote="")`. I had no idea this was there. I just removed it and the problem is now solved.

Comment: This may tell you [where to find the .Rprofile file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13736073/1577947).