# rJava 'class not found' error with makeCluster

Tags: r, parallel-processing, rjava

I'm having this issue for a while now and can't find answers online. I try to execute `makeCluster` and somehow get this

> Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
cores = makeCluster(2)
# Loading required package: methods
# Loading required package: DBI
# Loading required package: rJava
# Error in .jfindClass(as.character(driverClass)[1]) : class not found
# Calls: JDBC -> is.jnull -> .jfindClass
# Execution halted
```

Would anyone be able to help? Thanks.

Comment: In my version of R, your 3-line script doesn't call neither `DBI` nor `rJava` packages.

Comment: Are you loading any packages from a .Rprofile script? And are you setting any environment variables in order to successfully load the rJava package?

Comment: You got it, Steve. My .Rprofile had the line `library(RJDBC)` and the line `drv <- JDBC("com.sas.net.sharenet.ShareNetDriver",
    "/usr/local/sas/jdbc_driver/sas.intrnet.javatools.jar",
     identifier.quote="`")`. I had no idea this was there. I just removed it and now it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In your console first File-->changedir into your jar file location

then you try this one

drv <- JDBC(driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
   classPath="mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar",
   identifier.quote="`")