# x11 Full Screen in R programming

Tags: r, fullscreen, x11

I want to open full screen windows with x11() function in R. Default parameters:

```
x11(width = 7,height = 7)
```

How can I set these parameters full screen for every pc screen?

NOT: I use RStudio with R version 3.2.1

Comment: For example, you can edit the `.Rprofile` and modify the `grDevices::X11.options` inside the line starting with `setHook`.

Comment: How can I edit my .Rprofile. Please give me some explanation. I am new user in R.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options