# How to set the global default for R and Rstudio on Mac?

Tags: r, rstudio

Under Mac OSX, for the general default, normally I start the terminal and use `ls -al` to check the availability of the .bash_profile and then use `nano .bash_profile` to add the necessary global default into it. 
    But for R and Rstudio, if I want to set the global default for the input of the Chinese character with command `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_cn.utf-8")`. I use the following command to get the **R_HOME**

```
  R.home()
```

[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"

Then I copy the command `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_cn.utf-8")` into the newly created file named either .Rprofile or "Rprofile.site in the directory "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/etc", but it seems not work for me, what's wrong for my steps?
There is a close anwer to my question [locate the ".Rprofile" file generating default options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options)
What's the difference between .Rprofile and Rprofile.site?

Comment: I guess I know the answer, it's because I forget to press enter after the typing of `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "zh_cn.utf-8")`. the following link offers a good explanation for this https://csgillespie.github.io/efficientR/3-3-r-startup.html#r-startup

Comment: By the way, `file.path` has no effect in your code.

Comment: yes, you are right, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear but it seems that you’re asking for an equivalent to the configuration file `~/.bash_profile`. That would be `~/.Rprofile`. For more information, read the documentation on [“Initialization at Start of an R Session”](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html). This also answers your question “What's the difference between .Rprofile and Rprofile.site?”:

`$R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site` is the *site file*, whereas [`~/`]`.Rprofile` is the *user file*.

Comment: so if I want to add .Rprofile under etc instead of under directory ~/, I need to create a folder named Rprofile.site first?

Comment: @johnsonzhj Not a folder, a file, called `.Rprofile.site`. However, I’d generally (= always, except when explicitly targeting multiple users) prefer a user configuration over a site configuration.

Comment: Ic, so as a single user, what I need to do is just to create a *user* file .Rprofile rather than *site* file Rprofile.site?

Comment: @johnsonzhj Yes.