# How to plot Highcharter side by side in RStudio Viewer?

Tags: r, highcharts

I wanted to see an exact output of a Highcharter plot side by side in RStudio Viewer if it possible, exactly showed in this reference: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts.html, So let me define it like this for a simple usage

```
highcharter_all_plot <- function(){
  library(highcharter)
  library(dplyr)
  library(stringr)
  library(purrr)
  n <- 5
  set.seed(123)
  colors <- c("#d35400", "#2980b9", "#2ecc71", "#f1c40f", "#2c3e50", "#7f8c8d")
  colors2 <- c("#000004", "#3B0F70", "#8C2981", "#DE4968", "#FE9F6D", "#FCFDBF")

  df <- data.frame(x = seq_len(n) - 1) %>% 
    mutate(
      y = 10 + x + 10 * sin(x),
      y = round(y, 1),
      z = (x*y) - median(x*y),
      e = 10 * abs(rnorm(length(x))) + 2,
      e = round(e, 1),
      low = y - e,
      high = y + e,
      value = y,
      name = sample(fruit[str_length(fruit) <= 5], size = n),
      color = rep(colors, length.out = n),
      segmentColor = rep(colors2, length.out = n)
    )

  print(head(df))

  create_hc <- function(t) {
    dont_rm_high_and_low <- c("arearange", "areasplinerange",
                              "columnrange", "errorbar")
    is_polar <- str_detect(t, "polar")
    t <- str_replace(t, "polar", "")
    if(!t %in% dont_rm_high_and_low){
      df <- df %>% dplyr::select(-e, -low, -high)
    } 
    highchart() %>%
      hc_title(text = paste(ifelse(is_polar, "polar ", ""), t),
               style = list(fontSize = "15px")) %>% 
      hc_chart(type = t,
               polar = is_polar) %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = df$name) %>% 
      hc_add_series(df, name = "Fruit Consumption", showInLegend = FALSE) 
  }

  hcs <- c("line", "spline",  "area", "areaspline",
           "column", "bar", "waterfall" , "funnel", "pyramid",
           "pie" , "treemap", "scatter", "bubble",
           "arearange", "areasplinerange", "columnrange", "errorbar",
           "polygon", "polarline", "polarcolumn", "polarcolumnrange",
           "coloredarea", "coloredline")  %>% map(create_hc) 
  return(hcs)
}

x <- highcharter_all_plot()

#Then plot can be accessed in by calling x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]]..
```

As far as my understanding of side by side plot, I only know of 2 these handy methods, which is:

1) Using par(mfrow)

`par(mfrow=c(3,4))` -> (which only can by applied to base plot)

2) Using grid.arrange from gridExtra

```
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(x[[1]], x[[2]], x[[3]], x[[4]], nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

-> (Cannot work since x not a ggplot type)

So I wanted to know if there is a way that this can be applied? I am new using Highcharter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inspect the Highcharter website you provided, you will see that those charts are not sided by side using R, but they are just renderer in separate HTML containers and positioned by bootstrap (CSS). So, if you want to render your charts in an HTML environment, I suggest rendering every chart into a separate div.

But maybe **Shiny** is a tool you are looking for. Maybe this is a duplicate of [Shiny rcharts multiple chart output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895321/shiny-rcharts-multiple-chart-output)

Maybe this will help you too: https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/37

Comment: I see.. So Shiny may be the fit approach for Highcharter multiple plots .. Thanks @raf18seb for the references