# rprofile running multiple times

Tags: r, rprofile

My `.Rprofile` always runs twice. I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735745/locate-the-rprofile-file-generating-default-options)
and think it might be because the slashes are going in various directions.

I only have code in the paths pointing at `C:/Users/rileyj3/.Rprofile` (results 1, 2 & 4). Does anyone know how to resolve?

| expr | path | exists |
| --- | --- | --- |
| file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile") | C:/Users/rileyj3/.Rprofile | TRUE |
| file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile") | C:\Users\rileyj3/.Rprofile | TRUE |
| file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site") | C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/etc/Rprofile.site | TRUE |
| Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE") | C:\Users\rileyj3.Rprofile | TRUE |
| Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER") |  | FALSE |

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(
  expr = c(
        'file.path(getwd(), ".Rprofile")',
        'file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile")',
        'file.path(Sys.getenv("R_HOME"), "etc", "Rprofile.site")',
        'Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE")',
        'Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER")'
  )
) |> 
  mutate(
        path = map_chr(expr, ~parse(text = .x) |> eval()),
        exists = file.exists(path)
  ) |> 
  knitr::kable()
```

Comment: You nailed it. The One Drive at work took over my workspace and I had manually added R_PROFILE to my windows environment variables. I removed it, restarted my PC, and the problem is gone. If you add your suggestions as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the details of R read Rprofile files on the `?Startup` help page.

R will look for both a site-wide and user-specific profile. Since you have a value set for R_PROFILE, that's considered a site-wide profile so it's run. Then when R looks for a user-specific value, it finds the one in your home directory so it runs that one as well. R doesn't check to see if the site-wide and specific files are the same. You should probably remove the R_PROFILE system environment variable since you seem to be setting a user-specific values there or move it to R_PROFILE_USER.